# Ordenar um array de acordo com o número em cada item (misturado com letras)

Tags: javascript, array

Estou tentando ordenar um array de acordo com o numero em cada item. Deu certo para um caso e para outra caso não. A descrição da atividade é:

> Sua tarefa é classificar uma determinada string. Cada palavra na string conterá um único número. Este número é a posição que a palavra
> deve ter no resultado.
>
> Nota: Os números podem ser de 1 a 9. Portanto, 1 será a primeira
> palavra (não 0).
>
> Se a string de entrada estiver vazia, retorne uma string vazia. As
> palavras na String de entrada conterão apenas números consecutivos
> válidos.

O meu código funcionou para o teste 1 o qual a frase é

```
"is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"  -->  "Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
```

Mas não funcionou para o teste 2 o qual a frase é

```
"4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"  -->  "Fo1r the2 g3ood 4of th5e pe6ople"
""  -->  ""
```

meu código:

```js
function order(words){
      let divideWords = words.split(" "); // divide as palavras que recebe da string
      console.log(divideWords);
      let string1
      let numeroIndex
        
      for (k = 0; k < divideWords.length; k++){ // percorre os as palavras do array divideWords
        
      string1 = divideWords[k]; // a cada loop atribui uma palavra a string1
           for (i = 0 ; i < string1.length ; i++){ //percorre as letras da palavra para encontrar o numero
               if (Number(string1[i])) { //condiçao que detecta o numero da string
               numeroIndex = parseInt(string1[i]); // 
               let aux = divideWords[numeroIndex - 1]; //salva a palavra que estava la antes de substituir pela nova ordem correta
               divideWords[numeroIndex - 1] = string1; // substitui a palavra correta no index correto
               divideWords[k] = aux; // atribui a palavra salva anteriormente ao index antigo
        } 
      }
      }
      console.log(divideWords.toString().replace(/,/g," "));
      return divideWords.toString().replace(/,/g," "); // transforma o array em string e troca as virgulas por espaço voltando a uma frase
      
    }
```

teste 1:

```
> [ 'is2', 'Thi1s', 'T4est', '3a' ] 
> Thi1s is2 3a T4est
```

teste 2:

> [ '4of', 'Fo1r', 'pe6ople', 'g3ood', 'th5e', 'the2' ] Fo1r g3ood the2
> 4of th5e pe6ople

Comment: Em vez de usar o mesmo array `divideWords`, é mais simples criar outro array. E para juntar tudo em uma string, use o método `join`: https://ideone.com/C6B7yD

Comment: Claro, o que eu sugeri acima é apenas se os números forem sempre sequenciais e começando em 1. Se tiver "buracos" (por exemplo, se a frase só tiver 3, 5 e 9), aí o mais garantido é ordenar: https://ideone.com/JH4eLQ